# web3.getPastEvents return events but can't subscribe to an event

Tags: solidity, web3js, events

I have a contract which has an event. The contract's code is pretty simple:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.4;

import "./Crowdfunding.sol";

contract Factory {
    address[] public deployedCrowdfundings;

    event ContractDeployed(
        address crowdfundingAddress,
        address deployerAddress
    );

    function createCrowdfunding(uint256 minimumContribution) public {
        address newCrowdfunding =
            address(new Crowdfunding(minimumContribution, msg.sender));
        deployedCrowdfundings.push(newCrowdfunding);
        emit ContractDeployed(newCrowdfunding, msg.sender);
    }

    function getDeployedCrowdfundings() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return deployedCrowdfundings;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is with the events. If I call the method getPastEvents it returns me all the events:

```
factory.getPastEvents('ContractDeployed', {
        fromBlock: 0,
        toBlock: 'latest'
    }, function(error, events){ console.log(events); })
    .then(function(events){
        console.log(events) 
    });
```

But if I try to subscribe(I tried in 2 ways):
First way

```
factory.events.ContractDeployed({
    })
    .on("connected", function (subscriptionId){
        console.log(subscriptionId);
    })
    .on("data", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

Second way:

```
let eventName = "ContractDeployed";
    const eventJsonInterface = web3.utils._.find(
        factory._jsonInterface,
        o => o.name === eventName && o.type === 'event',
    )
    
    const subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
        address: factory.options.address,
        topics: [eventJsonInterface.signature]
    }, (error, result) => {
        if (!error) {
            const eventObj = web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(
                eventJsonInterface.inputs,
                result.data,
                result.topics.slice(1)
            )
            console.log(`New ${eventName}!`, eventObj)
        }
        if (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
```

Both give me the following error:

```
Error: Returned error: Method not found
    at Object.ErrorResponse (E:\Solidity\Kickstarter\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:28:19)
    at Object.callback (E:\Solidity\Kickstarter\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\lib\index.js:303:36)
    at E:\Solidity\Kickstarter\node_modules\web3-providers-ws\lib\index.js:114:45
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at WebsocketProvider._onMessage (E:\Solidity\Kickstarter\node_modules\web3-providers-ws\lib\index.js:102:69)
    at W3CWebSocket._dispatchEvent [as dispatchEvent] (E:\Solidity\Kickstarter\node_modules\yaeti\lib\EventTarget.js:115:12)
    at W3CWebSocket.onMessage (E:\Solidity\Kickstarter\node_modules\websocket\lib\W3CWebSocket.js:234:14)
    at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (E:\Solidity\Kickstarter\node_modules\websocket\lib\W3CWebSocket.js:205:19)
    at WebSocketConnection.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at WebSocketConnection.processFrame (E:\Solidity\Kickstarter\node_modules\websocket\lib\WebSocketConnection.js:554:26)
    at E:\Solidity\Kickstarter\node_modules\websocket\lib\WebSocketConnection.js:323:40
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  data: null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need a WebSocket connection to subscribe to live events. HTTP protocol is one-way and does not offer push.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I solved it, thanks.